# Does JSON have a schema?

Tags: java, json, web-services, schema

Do JSON / RESTful Web services have a schema equivalent to a wsdl?

If the answer is no, then how do two sides agree on a shared format?

If the answer is yes, are there any tools to auto generate JSON Java client/server from the schema?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JSON has [a schema](http://json-schema.org/). REST services have [WADL](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/).

Also there are tools like [`wadl2java`](http://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html).

Comment: Old question, but worth clarifying: The JSON Schema standard includes "hyper-schemas", which specify links/actions - including HTTP method, required data (specified as JSON Schema), and expected results.  It should be possible to fully explore a JSON API just by paying attention to the schemas.

Comment: I would also like to mention this nice tutorial instead of starting with the specifications: https://brandur.org/elegant-apis. The next JSON Schema draft will be 0.5 and it is discussed here: https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/v5-Proposals

Answer (score 6):

I is possible to have a schema for restful web services and some tools support this.  But it is common for restful web services to be published without the publishing organisation providing a machine readable schema.

Usually they provide some human readable documentation describing the structure of the JSON.  The consumer writes a simple hand written library to consume it (much easer than it sounds in practice with modern tools) or the publisher provides a client library for users to use.

Also JSON/RESTfull web services tend to be carefully designed to deliver simple datastructers over the wire which are easy to consume. Do you need a schema for a list?